# Django: TemplateDoesNotExist at / home.html in my project

Tags: django, django-templates

I can not understand why django can't search 'home.html'

my project name is `lucifer`

here's my tree of projects

```
│   ├── lucifer
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── settings
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── development.py
│   │   │   ├── partials
│   │   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   │   ├── base.py
│   │   │   │   ├── database.py
│   │   │   │   └── static.py
│   │   │   └── production.py
│   │   ├── templates
│   │   │   ├── base.html
│   │   │   ├── home.html
│   │   │   └── partials
│   │   │       ├── footer.html
│   │   │       └── header.html
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   ├── views
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── home.py
```

and my **`home.html`**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
Home
{% endblock %}
```

**`header.html`**

```
<p>it is header</p>
```

**`footer.html`**

```
<p>it is footer</p>
```

**`base.html`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>루시퍼 |{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>

    {% include 'partials/header.html' %}

    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}

    {% include 'partials/footer.html' %}

</body>
</html>
```

**`home.py`**

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


class Home(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'
```

**`urls.py`**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'$^', Home.as_view(), name='home'),
]
```

I think it has no problem..

but error is

```
Django version 1.9.7, using settings 'lucifer.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/lucifer/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 174, in get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/lucifer/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 172, in get_response
response = response.render()
  File "/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/lucifer/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 160, in render
self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/lucifer/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 135, in rendered_content
template = self._resolve_template(self.template_name)
  File "/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/lucifer/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 90, in _resolve_template
new_template = self.resolve_template(template)
  File "/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/lucifer/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 80, in resolve_template
return select_template(template, using=self.using)
  File "/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/lucifer/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 74, in select_template
raise TemplateDoesNotExist(', '.join(template_name_list), chain=chain)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: home.html
[06/Feb/2017 07:40:34] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 81753
```

please tell me some advise thank you

ADD **`TEMPLATES`** in settings.partials.base.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Can you post your `TEMPLATES` var please?

Comment: @arcegk um.. sorry I can't understand you comment What is Templates var? if it is variable template code, I insert this code in my question

Comment: @MinHan, the TEMPLATES configuration should be somewhere in your settings files. If you’re on Mac or Unix, try running `grep TEMPLATES`, or just look inside files manually.

Comment: I mean the `TEMPLATES` variable located in one of your settings files

Comment: Can you post the whole project structure? If lucifer is a sub app django won't pick up the templates.

Comment: I solved my problem restart django-admin project, But I sincerely thank all those who gave me advice for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Be sure to put `lucifer` inside your `settings.py`'s `INSTALLED_APPS`
`APPS_DIR=True` will tell Django to [look inside your installed apps](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATES-APP_DIRS).

Comment: This is the correct way to do things. The other answers that add the templates directory to the `TEMPLATES` setting will work, but are an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 4):

This what we do for my currently project...

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        #'DIRS': [],
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'lucifer/templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

                # Enable {{ STATIC_URL }} and {{ MEDIA_URL }}
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), ],
        'APP_DIRS': '',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
            ],
            'loaders':[
                'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
            ]

        },

    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(dirname(dirname(__file__)), '..')+'/templates']
```

Add this in Template []

Answer (score 0):

Hey add templates folder to main project dir:

```
├── calc
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   └── views.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── first_django
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   └── wsgi.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
└── **templates**
    └── home.html
```

Answer (score 0):

import os and define the directory in Templates directory from setting. It works.

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your templates folder is the root directory location and add the following to settings.py.

```
'DIRS': ["templates"],
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).