# Django and Tailwind 'TemplateDoesNotExist' error

Tags: python, django, tailwind-css

I am following this tutoiral: https://www.ordinarycoders.com/blog/article/django-tailwind

I have a django project called 'project' with two apps in it 'app' and 'main'. I'm trying to load **'main > template > main > home.html'**. but I get this error:

```
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "C:\Users\Kaij\Documents\djangoTests\djangoTailwind2\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner     
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Kaij\Documents\djangoTests\djangoTailwind2\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response 
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kaij\Documents\djangoTests\djangoTailwind2\env\project\main\views.py", line 5, in homepage
    return render(request = request, template_name="main/home.html")  
  File "C:\Users\Kaij\Documents\djangoTests\djangoTailwind2\env\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\Kaij\Documents\djangoTests\djangoTailwind2\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 61, in render_to_string  
    template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\Kaij\Documents\djangoTests\djangoTailwind2\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 19, in get_template      
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: main/home.html       
[17/Nov/2021 11:49:03] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 80436
```

Following the tutorial, I have in my **'settings.py'**:

```
"""
Django settings for project project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.9.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = _____________________[blanked out]_____________________

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'tailwind',
    'app',
    'main',
]

TAILWIND_APP_NAME = 'app'
NPM_BIN_PATH = r"C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd"

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

TAILWIND_APP_NAME = 'app'

ROOT_URLCONF = 'project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['C:\Users\Kaij\Documents\djangoTests\djangoTailwind2\env\project\main\template'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'project.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

In my **project>urls.py** I have:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include  #add include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include ('main.urls')),   #add this
]
```

In my **main>urls.py**:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "main"   


urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.homepage, name="homepage"),
]
```

In **main>views.py** I have

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def homepage(request):
    return render(request = request, template_name="main/home.html")
```

I've tried to add the template directory of main into DIRS in settings.py follwing this other Stack link:  [Django: TemplateDoesNotExist at / home.html in my project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42062630/django-templatedoesnotexist-at-home-html-in-my-project)

But I haven't been able to open the html file.

Any help greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: The missing "s" after "template" in "main > template > main > home.html" is a typo or you accidentally named your `templates` directory as `template`?

Comment: @Dauros thanks do much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey change this line in your `settings.py`
from this

```
        'DIRS': ['C:\Users\Kaij\Documents\djangoTests\djangoTailwind2\env\project\main\template'],
```

to this

```
 [BASE_DIR/ 'templates']
```

and then in your `main` directory create a folder called `templates` and within that folder create another folder called main and that is where your `home.html` goes into. so something like this

```
project -> main -> templates -> home.html
```

and in your folder called main, create a `urls.py` and add these lines

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import some_view_name

urlpatterns = [
    path('', some_view_name, name='home-view')
]
```

then in main -> views.py add this line to

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def some_view_name(request):
    return render(request, "main/home.html")
```

that should some the problem for you.

your directory structure should look like something like this

```
project 
    -> project
          urls.py
           ...
    -> main
          ->templates
            -> main
                 -> home.html
   manage.py
   ...
```

If this solves your problem please don't forget to accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks so much Kevin. Also Dauros suggestion combined with yours did the trick